# How to measure performance test on java method?

Tags: performance, testing

I have a method in java

```
Public Object someMethod (String param) (
//some calculations
Return Object )
```

I want to test the performance of this method ( how much time would it take to reach to db and return an object ) 
How can I do this? 
I don't have a main method because its a library. I use unit tests to check if it works. 
Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use JMH, which is an excellent framework for doing microbenchmarks

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/

It is used all the time by engineers that develops the JDK.